# Count numbers without Zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query who works correctly, but where I want to make a change.
The query counts all notes for `id_service = 89`.
The notes are numbers between 0 and 3 not more.
My query counts all those notes to get an Average.
All works fine.

The change what I want is, that he counts only the notes between 1 and 3 (not 0).
I don't know how I can do that.

Example:

This query count how much time I get the number 3 with all conditions.
Here the query:

```
SELECT round( avg( AVG =3 ) * count( AVG ) ) AS New
     , sma_famille.famille
FROM (              
    SELECT ROUND( SUM( note ) / count( note ) ) AS AVG
         , sma_famille.famille
         , sma_agents.nom
    FROM sma_notes
        INNER JOIN sma_famille 
            ON sma_famille.id_service =89
        INNER JOIN sma_agents 
            ON sma_notes.id_agent = sma_agents.id_agent
        INNER JOIN sma_service_activite 
            ON sma_service_activite.id_activite = sma_notes.id_activite
            AND sma_service_activite.id_famille = sma_famille.id_famille
            AND sma_service_activite.id_service = sma_famille.id_service
    GROUP BY sma_famille.famille, sma_agents.nom
) AS FN
LEFT JOIN sma_famille 
    ON sma_famille.id_service =89
    AND FN.famille = sma_famille.famille
GROUP BY FN.famille
```

An example:
In Bio I can give 2 notes per persons like Bio Part1 and Bio Part2.

In my example I have two persons.
I give in Bio Part1 the note "3" for both and in Bio Part2 i don't give a note, so that there are the note "0"!

Here the result of my query:

That is what I get:

```
     Note  Math   English   Bio  
     1      0       0       0 
     2      0       0       2 
     3      0       0       0
```

That is what I want:

```
     Note  Math   English   Bio  
     1      0       0       0 
     2      0       0       0 
     3      0       0       2
```

Without the note "0" I must get an average of 100% for the note "3".

Now i get:

```
     Note  Math   English   Bio  
     1                      0 
     2                      0 
     3                      2
```

And not

```
     Note  Math   English   Bio  
     1      0       0       0 
     2      0       0       0 
     3      0       0       2
```

How can i get the "0" in the resultset

Anybody an idea?

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: sounds roughly like you want the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Hello
THX for the answer
i edit my question with an better example

Comment: The structure of your supplied output does not match that of your supplied query. To put it another way: you cannot get that output from that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get a count of values > 0 would be:

```
count(case when note > 0 then note end)
```

(Where note is 0, the case evaluates as null which is not counted.)

Although the simplest way might be

```
sum(sign(note))
```

Comment: Yeah Great it works, but how can i get "0" for the others in the Resultset? Now i get Null.
THX

Comment: @achilix: Can you rephrase your last comment? I don't understand it.